# Remove options "Remove" and "Add related items" in Related Items field

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to delete "REMOVE" and "ADD RELATED ITEMS" from a Related Items type field (DispForm/EditForm) in Sharepoint 2013. I want the field show up but without these two options.

I have already tried to upload a JSLINK based on the link: https://www.blumshapiro.com/insights/customize-related-items-field-in-sharepoint-2013/, adding it into DispForm web part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide the elements by CSS.

Try to insert below style to display form(script editor webpart, I tested in my local 2013).

```
<style>
.ms-relateditems-deletelink{
display:none !important;
}
div.ms-relateditems-core a.ms-calloutLink{
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Great! It worked like a charm. I really appreciate your help on it.